# In a Rails view how do I reference the object passed to respond_with in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, respond-with

Say I have the following:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  responds_to :html

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@project)
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  responds_to :html

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@user)
  end
end
```

Is there a method I can use to reference the object passed to respond_with in the layouts/application.html.erb template without needing to know the assigned variable's name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no method(at least I didn't hear about such method). But if you want you can look here, it is pretty nice solution: [Decent exposure](http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure)

I hope I helped you alittle.